Adapter becomes null when we change theme and the app crashes when we use addTask function
I have the following fragment class:
public class ToDoFragment extends Fragment {

Context context;
LinearLayout no_tasks;
RecyclerView tasks_list;
ToDoRecyclerAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Task_Model> arrTask;

public ToDoFragment(){

}

public ToDoFragment(ArrayList<Task_Model> arrTask){
    this.arrTask = arrTask;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_do, container, false);

    tasks_list = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tasks_list);       

    no_tasks = rootView.findViewById(R.id.no_tasks);

    context = requireActivity().getApplicationContext();

    tasks_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        arrTask = (ArrayList<Task_Model>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("tasks");
    }

    adapter = new ToDoRecyclerAdapter(arrTask);
    tasks_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    if(tasksPresent()){
        no_tasks.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        no_tasks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("tasks", arrTask);
}

public void addTask(String task_name, String task_desc, char priority){

    arrTask.add(new Task_Model(task_name, task_desc, priority));

    if(adapter != null) {
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(arrTask.size() - 1);
    }

}

public boolean tasksPresent(){

    return arrTask.size() > 0;

}

}
I am expecting that when I use addTask function after shifting theme from dark to light or light to dark, the adapter must not be null, how to fix this. I am making an app which looks like google tasks but the app crashes when I switch theme and adapter becomes null. how to fix this.

pls provide you adapter code also

If your Adapter becomes null the safest approach is by initializing the adapter in onCreateView regardless of the state of savedInstanceState, you ensure that the adapter is never null when the fragment is recreated due to a theme change.
try adding this code to your onCreateView method
adapter = new ToDoRecyclerAdapter(arrTask);
tasks_list.setAdapter(adapter);

before the
tasks_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

part
